# why button not showing in custom theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, theme, css, color-swatches

> when i go customer login and customer module and custom_module related
>   pages
>
> button is not showing

[image]

when **i move a mouse over that button  the button 
is showing**

how to solve this css color issue

[image]

> when untick the default css in inspect element
>   button color is showing 
>   how i fix this..???

[image]

Comment: add the css for your button to your custom theme's css

Comment: where..................

Comment: from here `app\design\frontend\YourThemeVendor\yourThemeName\Magento_Theme\web\css\custom.css`

Comment: for my custom module

Comment: is this in frontend?

Comment: ss.................
also check my question is updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91581/discussion-between-magefms-and-prabhakaran7).

Comment: did you fix it? or my suggested solution works?

Comment: this is not fixed yet ...

Comment: did you try solution below

Comment: this color problem also affects in other buttons

Comment: di you create the button or it is default?

Comment: i tried but only tempory solution for that answer

Comment: the default button in magento  
that colors are theme colors

Comment: maybe use class name instead of an id, like .login

Comment: you can try `.primary.action.primary{
    background: #0088cc !important; /* color blue, you can change according to your needs */
} `

Comment: ok  i will try..

Comment: okay and let me know if it works or not

Comment: hm  sure..........

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/267807/73525    could you help for this..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **custom css** in order to fix that one.
In your case, using a **custom module** you can insert your custom css to the head block of your Magento webshop.

Try this:

> 1. create a **custom.css** file inside **`vendor\module\view\frontend\web\css\custom.css`**

and put this code:

```
/* your button id is send2 */    
#send2{
    background: #0088cc !important; /* color blue, you can change according to your needs */
}
```

> 2. Then create a **default.xml** in your layout folder **`vendor\module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`**

and put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="vendor_module::css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

After doing the above solution, please run an upgrade and redeploy static contents.
Note: **`vendor`** is your vendor name and **`module`** is your module name.

Then check if it works.