# my custom module pages title's are moved to bottom in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, xml, customer-account, page-title

have custom module and pages

here

> my module and customer dashboard **title's are moved to the bottom**

that module xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <head>
            <css src="Webkul_Mpquotesystem::css/mpquotesystem.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Block\Mpbuyerquotes" name="mpqs_list" template="Webkul_Mpquotesystem::buyer/quotelist.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

phtml file

```
<?php
/**
 * Webkul Software
 *
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Mpquotesystem
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2018 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
$deleteImage = $block->getImageUrl('Webkul_Marketplace::images/icon-trash.png');
$editImage = $block->getImageUrl('Webkul_Marketplace::images/icon-edit.png');
$attachIcon = $block->getImageUrl('Webkul_Mpquotesystem::images/attachmenticon.png');
$quoteHelper = $this->helper('Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Helper\Data');
?>
<div class="wk_mp_design">
    <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
        <?php if (count($block->getQuotesCollection())==0) {
            ?>       
            <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                <div class="wk_emptymsg">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('No Quotes Available') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $block->getUrl(
                'mpquotesystem/buyerquote/massdeletequote',
                ['_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()]
            ) ?>" method="post" id="formmassdelete" name="formmassdelete">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                <button class="button"
                title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Delete Quotes') ?>"
                type="submit"
                id="mass_delete_butn"
                >
                    <span><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Delete Quotes') ?></span></span>
                </button>
                <table cellspacing="0" class="data table mpquote-list">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="col selectid">
                                <span>
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                    name="mpquoteselecctall"
                                    value="all"
                                    id="mpquoteselecctall"/>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col proname">
                                <span class="label name">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Product Name')?>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col quote_qty">
                                <span class="label qty">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Quantity')?>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col quote_price">
                                <span class="label qty">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Quote Price')?>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col attachment">
                                <span class="label">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Attachment')?>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col status">
                                <span class="label">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Status')?>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col action">
                                <span class="label">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Action')?>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 0;
                    foreach ($block->getQuotesCollection() as $quote) { ?>
                        <tr 
                            class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $class = ($i == count(
                                $block->getQuotesCollection()
                            ))? 'wk_last_tr':''?>">
                            <input 
                                type="hidden"
                                class="id"
                                value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getId(); ?>"
                            >
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("ID")?>" class="col selectid">
                                    <span>
                                        <?php if ($block->quoteStatusIsNotSold($quote->getStatus())) { ?>
                                            <input type="checkbox"
                                            name="quote_mass_delete[]"
                                            class="mpquotecheckbox"
                                            value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getId(); ?>"/>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Product Name")?>" class="col proname">
                                    <span class="label">
                                        <?php $product = $quoteHelper->getProduct($quote->getProductId());?>
                                        <?php
                                            if ($quoteHelper->checkProductCanShowOrNot($product)) : ?>
                                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $product->getProductUrl()?>" target="blank">
                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $product->getName(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getProductName(); ?>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Quantity")?>" class="col quote_qty wk_qs_quote_qty">
                                    <span class="label qty">
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getQuoteQty(); ?>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Quote Price")?>" class="col quote_price">
                                    <span class="label">
                                        <input type="hidden" 
                                        class="wk_qs_quote_price"
                                        value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getQuotePrice(); ?>">
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quoteHelper->getformattedPrice(
                                            $quote->getQuotePrice()
                                        ); ?>
                                    </span> 
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Attachment")?>" class="col quote_attachment">
                                    <span class="label">
                                    <?php if($quote->getAttachment()) : ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $block->getAttchment($quote->getAttachment())?>" target="_blank"/>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $attachIcon?>"></img>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php else : ?>
                                        <span><?php echo __('N/A') ?></span>
                                    <?php endif ; ?>
                                    </span> 
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Status")?>" class="col status">        
                                    <span class="label pro_status">
                                        <?php if ($quote->getStatus() == \Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\Quotes::STATUS_UNAPPROVED) { ?>
                                            <span class="label wk_qs_status_pending">
                                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Pending')?>
                                            </span>
                                        <?php } elseif ($quote->getStatus() == \Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\Quotes::STATUS_APPROVED) { ?>
                                            <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">
                                                <span>
                                                    <span>
                                                        <span>
                                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Add To Cart"); ?>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                            </button>
                                        <?php } elseif ($quote->getStatus() == \Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Model\Quotes::STATUS_DECLINE) { ?>
                                            <span class="label wk_qs_status_decline">
                                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Declined')?>
                                            </span>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <span class="label wk_qs_status_sold">
                                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Sold')?>
                                            </span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </span>
                                </td>                                   
                                <td data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __("Action")?>" class="col action">
                                    <span class="label wk_action">
                                        <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $editImage?>"
                                        data-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getId();?>" 
                                        alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Edit')?>" 
                                        data-url = "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $block->getUrl(
                                            'mpquotesystem/buyerquote/edit/',
                                            [
                                                'id'=>$quote->getEntityId(),
                                                '_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()
                                            ]
                                        ) ?>"
                                        title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Edit')?>" 
                                        class="mp_quote_edit"/>
                                    <?php if ($block->quoteStatusIsNotSold($quote->getStatus())) { ?>
                                        <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $deleteImage?>"
                                        alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Delete')?>"
                                        title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Delete')?>"
                                        class="mp_quote_delete"
                                        data-url = "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $block->getUrl(
                                            'mpquotesystem/buyerquote/delete/',
                                            [
                                                'id'=>$quote->getEntityId(),
                                                '_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()
                                            ]
                                        ) ?>"
                                        data-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo $quote->getId();?>"/>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </span> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        <?php }?>
        </div>
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$formData = [
    'mpquoteedit'       =>   '.mp_quote_edit',
    'mpmassdelete'      =>  '#mass_delete_butn',
    'mpquotecheckbox'   =>  '.mpquotecheckbox',
    'massdeleteform'    =>  '#formmassdelete',
    'mpselectall'       =>  '#mpquoteselecctall',
    'mpquotedelete'     =>  '.mp_quote_delete',
    'mpquotestatus'     =>  '.pro_status button',
    'addtocarturl'      =>  $block->getUrl(
        'mpquotesystem/buyerquote/addtocart',
        ['_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()]
    ),
    'checkoutpageurl'   =>  $block->getUrl(
        'checkout/cart/index',
        ['_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()]
    ),
    'customerloginUrl'  =>  $block->getUrl(
        'customer/account/login',
        ['_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()]
    )

];
$serializedFormData = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($formData);
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "WkMpQuotesystem": <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $serializedFormData; ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

how i fix this???

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code? Kind of hard to tell whats the problem right now.

Comment: hm sure..........

Comment: can you include the template file buyer/quotelist.phtml

Comment: hm wait.........

Comment: added.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>
```

in `\app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Customer\layout\customer_account.xml`

Thanks

Comment: <move element="page.main.title" destination="content.top" before="-"/>

already have this line

Comment: @prabhakaran7 please change destination from content.top to content

Comment: thank you  can get your email id for future contact